# What does this mean in Perl 1..$#something?

Tags: perl

I have a loop for example :

```
for my $something ( @place[1..$#thing] ) {

}
```

I don't get this statement `1..$#thing`

I know that # is for comments but my IDE doesn't color #thing as comment. Or is it really just a comment for someone to know that what is in **"$"** is **"thing"** ? And if it's a comment why was the rest of the line not commented out like `] ) {` ?

If it has other meanings, i will like to know. Sorry if my question sounds odd, i am just new to perl and perplexed by such an expression.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `$#` is the syntax for getting the highest index of the array in question, so `$#thing` is the highest index of the array `@thing`. This is documented in [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

`..` is the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators), and `1 .. $#thing` means a list of numbers, from 1 to whatever the highest index of `@thing` is.

Using this list inside array brackets with the `@` sigill denotes that this is an array *slice*, which is to say, a selected number of elements in the `@place` array.

So assuming the following:

```
my @thing = qw(foo bar baz);
my @place = qw(home work restaurant gym);
```

then `@place[1 .. $#thing]` (or `1 .. 2`) would expand into the list `work, restaurant`.

It is correct that `#` is used for comments, but not in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed explanation. I appreciate. For it is now clear :)

Answer (score 1):

it's how you define a range.  From starting value to some other value.

```
for my $something ( @place[1..3] ) { 
    # Takes the first three elements
}
```

> Binary ".." is the range operator, which is really two different
>   operators depending on the context. In list context, it returns a list
>   of values counting (up by ones) from the left value to the right
>   value. If the left value is greater than the right value then it
>   returns the empty list. The range operator is useful for writing
>   foreach (1..10) loops and for doing slice operations on arrays. In the
>   current implementation, no temporary array is created when the range
>   operator is used as the expression in foreach loops, but older
>   versions of Perl might burn a lot of memory when you write something
>   like this:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does explain it :) I now know what it's about